# How to control other widgets with an QAbstractTableModel model?

Tags: python, qt, model, pyqt, qtableview

The `QTableView` is controlled by `QAbstractTableModel`. It is the model that populates its content. And it is the model that modifies `self.items` variable by writing to it as a result of the user double-clicking one of the `QTableView`'s items and then entering a new value.

The button at the bottom of my dialog box is initially disabled. I want this button to get enabled as soon as the user enters a new value (by double-clicking any one of `QTableView`'s items and typing a string or a number).

Essentially I want the model to control the button's state. How can I achieve it?

[image]

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys, os

class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.items =[ 
                    ['Row0_Column0','Row0_Column1','Row0_Column2'],
                    ['Row1_Column0','Row1_Column1','Row1_Column2'],
                    ['Row2_Column0','Row2_Column1','Row2_Column2']
                    ]

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.items)       
    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 3

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return QVariant()
        row=index.row()
        column=index.column()

        if row>len(self.items): return QVariant()        
        if column>len(self.items[row]): return QVariant()

        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            return QVariant(self.items[row][column])

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:            
            return QVariant(self.items[row][column])

        return QVariant()

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if index.isValid():            
            if role == Qt.EditRole:
                row = index.row()
                column=index.column()
                if row>len(self.items) or column>len(self.items[row]):
                    return False
                else:
                    self.items[row][column]=value  
                    return True
        return False

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        tablemodel=Model(self)               
        tableview=QTableView(self) 
        tableview.setModel(tablemodel)    
        layout=QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(tableview)
        self.button=QPushButton('Push Me')
        self.button.setDisabled(True)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I'm not fond of Python but i can give you a hint. You can use `void QAbstractItemModel::​dataChanged(...)` signal to know when a user enter a new value by double clicking on a cell. You connect this signal to a slot where you get the new cell content in a string format and actualize the push button with this new string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28092837/how-to-control-arbitrary-widgets-with-model#comment44567307_28092837) is already a good starting point, but in your custom model you also have to emit a dataChanged signal in the setData method in order for it to work.

Then you could also define your own custom signals and emit them and connect for them. However, here is your example with the dataChanged signal of QAbstractItemModel:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Model(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.items =[ 
                    ['Row0_Column0','Row0_Column1','Row0_Column2'],
                    ['Row1_Column0','Row1_Column1','Row1_Column2'],
                    ['Row2_Column0','Row2_Column1','Row2_Column2']
                    ]

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.items)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 3

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        row=index.row()
        column=index.column()

        if row > len(self.items):
            return None
        if column > len(self.items[row]):
            return None

        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            return self.items[row][column]

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.items[row][column]

        return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if index.isValid():            
            if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:

                row = index.row()
                column = index.column()

                if row > len(self.items) or column > len(self.items[row]):
                    return False
                else:
                    self.items[row][column] = value
                    self.dataChanged.emit(index, index) # emit the signal
                    return True
        return False

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

        tablemodel = Model(self)
        tablemodel.dataChanged.connect(self.data_changed) # connect dataChanged signal
        tableview = QtGui.QTableView(self)
        tableview.setModel(tablemodel)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(tableview)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Push Me')
        self.button.setDisabled(True) # initially disabled

        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def data_changed(self, topleft_index, bottom_right_index):
        # just enable the button
        self.button.setEnabled(True)

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
w = MyWindow()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

The commented lines are the important ones.